# How can I make a monoid-like interface in C#?

Tags: c#, functional-programming

I want to require things which implement an interface (or derive from a class) to have an implementation for `Aggregate` included. That is, if they are of type `T` I want them to have something of type `Func<T,T,T>`. In Haskell this is called a "monoid".

*EDIT*: What I want to call is something like this:

```
list.Aggregate((x, accum) => accump.MAppend(x));
```

Based on DigalD's answer, this is my best attempt, but it doesn't compile:

```
interface IMonoid<T>
{
    T MAppend(T other);
}

class Test
{
    public static void runTest<T>(IEnumerable<IMonoid<T>> list)
    {
        // doesn't work
        list.Aggregate((x, ac) => ac.MAppend(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: by aggregate you mean a fold?

Comment: Remove the "public" keyword and the interface will compile.  If not, post more code...

Comment: Diego: Yes, most languages call this "fold". Not sure why C# went with "Aggregate". @David: I updated the code - that isn't the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Apocalisp looks closest to the mark, but I'd prefer something like this:

```
public interface IMonoid<T>
{
    T Combine(T x, T y);
    T Identity { get; }
}
```

While Haskell calls the monoid *identity* `mempty`, I think it's more reasonable to use the language of abstract algebra, so I named the identity value `Identity`. Likewise, I prefer the term `Combine` over Haskell's `mappend`, because the word *append* seems to indicate some sort of list append operation, which it doesn't have to be at all. `Combine`, however, isn't a perfect word either, because neither the *first* nor the *last* monoids combine the values; instead, they ignore one of them. I'm open to suggestions of a better name for the binary operation...

(In Haskell, BTW, I prefer using the `<>` operator alias instead of the `mappend` function, so that sort of side-steps the naming issue...)

Using the above `IMonoid<T>` interface, you can now write an extension method like this:

```
public static class Monoid
{
    public static T Concat<T>(this IMonoid<T> m, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        return values.Aggregate(m.Identity, (acc, x) => m.Combine(acc, x));
    }
}
```

Here, I completely arbitrarily and inconsistently decided to go with Haskell's naming, so I named the method `Concat`.

As I describe in my article [Monoids accumulate](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/11/20/monoids-accumulate), one always has to start the accumulation with the monoidal identity, in this case `m.Identity`.

As I describe in my article [Semigroups accumulate](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/12/11/semigroups-accumulate), instead of an imperative `for` loop, you can use the `Aggregate` extension method, but you'll have to use the overload that takes an initial seed value. That seed value is `m.Identity`.

You can now define various monoids, such as `Sum`:

```
public class Sum : IMonoid<int>
{
    public int Combine(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public int Identity
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
```

or `Product`:

```
public class Product : IMonoid<int>
{
    public int Combine(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    public int Identity
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Since I made the monoid argument the `this` argument of the `Concat` method, the method extends the `IMonoid<T>` interface, rather than `IEnumerable<T>`. I think this gives you a more readable API. For example:

```
var s = new Sum().Concat(new[] { 1000, 300, 30, 7 });
```

produces `s == 1337`, while

```
var p = new Product().Concat(new[] { 2, 3, 7 });
```

produces `p == 42`.

If you don't like having to create a `new Sum()` or `new Product()` object every time, you can make your monoids [Singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), like this `All` monoid:

```
public class All : IMonoid<bool>
{
    public static All Instance = new All();

    private All() { }

    public bool Combine(bool x, bool y)
    {
        return x && y;
    }

    public bool Identity
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
var a = All.Instance.Concat(new[] { true, true, true });
```

Here, `a` is `true`. You can use a similarly written `Any` monoid in the same way:

```
var a = Any.Instance.Concat(new[] { false, true, false });
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out how `Any` is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

A monoid is an associative operation together with an identity for that operation.

```
interface Monoid<T> {
  T MAppend(T t1, T t2);
  T MEmpty
}
```

The contract of a monoid is that for all `a`, `b`, and `c`:

1. Associativity: `MAppend(Mappend(a, b), c)` = `MAppend(a, Mappend(b, c))`
2. Left identity: `MAppend(MEmpty, a)` = `a`
3. Right identity: `MAppend(a, MEmpty)` = `a`

You can use it to add up the elements in a list:

```
class Test {
  public static T runTest<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Monoid<T> m) {
    list.Aggregate(m.MEmpty, (a, b) => m.MAppend(a, b));
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea, but these should really be static methods if the interface is specified like that.

Comment: No, they're actually instance methods. The `T` and the `Monoid<T>` are different objects.

Comment: And yet this code woudln't be able to sum up a list of ints.  Better to not use interfaces for this: `public static T Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> summables, T zero, Func<T, T, T> add) { return summables.Aggregate(zero, add); }`

Comment: It absolutely can sum a list of ints. All you need is a `Monoid<int>` which is trivial to write.

Answer (score 0):

What about this version:

```
interface IMonoid<T>
{
    T MAppend(IMonoid<T> other);
}

class Test
{
    public static void runTest<T>(IEnumerable<IMonoid<T>> list)
        where T : IMonoid<T>
    {
        list.Aggregate((x, ac) => ac.MAppend(x));
    }
}
```

Or better yet, enforcing it from the start:

```
interface IMonoid<T>
    where T : IMonoid<T>
{
    T MAppend(IMonoid<T> other);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you just make the Interface generic as well?

```
interface IMonoid<T>
{
    public IMonoidHandler<T> handler {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Can you see my edit? I don't think I can do it the way you propose, as I won't be able to call `list.Aggregate` correctly.